# pdo->exec undefined when testing

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I have a Connection.php file where i create a PDO connection in the constructor. But when i want to use this in the tests it fails and gives me the **Error: Call to undefined method App\model\Connection::exec()**

**Connection.php**

```
namespace App\model;

use \PDO;

class Connection
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($dsn, $user = null, $password = null)
    {
        $this->pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
            PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
    }

    public function getPDO()
    {
        return $this->pdo;
    }
}
```

**PDOMessageModelTest.php**

```
namespace App\Tests\Util;

use App\model\PDOMessageModel; 
use App\model\Connection; 
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase; 
use \PDO;

class PDOMessageModelTest extends TestCase {
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->connection = new Connection('sqlite::memory:');

        $this->connection->getPDO()->exec('CREATE TABLE message (
                        id INT,
                        content VARCHAR(1000),
                        category VARCHAR(100),
                        user_id INT,
                        upvotes INT,
                        downvotes INT,
                        PRIMARY KEY (id)
                   )');
```

**var_dump( $this->connection->getPDO()); die();** gives me the following output:
tests\PDOMessageModelTest.php:15:class PDO#352 (0) {
}

Comment: Could you add this line  : `var_dump( $this->connection->getPDO()); die(); ` just before  $this->connection->getPDO()->exec   call and take a screenshot of the result

Comment: @CheikhHAIBALA this is the output i get
tests\PDOMessageModelTest.php:15:class PDO#352 (0) { }

Comment: This code is working for me. The error message and your code are not lining up. `getPDO` is clearly returning your `PDO` instance so it's very odd that the error indicates that `exec` is being called on your connection class.

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace for your error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i don't see why you need to call exec() in your test. 
generally when we do unit tests  we mock all classes or functions that are not within the tested class.

you should do something like this if you need to test  a doSomething() method in a given class.

see the doc  [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/test-doubles.html)

```
               public function testStub()
                {
                    // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
                    $stub = $this->createMock(PDO::class);

                    // Configure the stub.
                    $stub->method('exec')
                         ->willReturn('true');

                    // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
                    // 'foo'.
                    $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething());
                }
```